# Edittext and KeyListener

Tags: android, eclipse, keylistener

I have an edittext and a keylistener. I want as soon as I press some keys (for example 0 or 1) to be done something, without the keys to be written on the edittext. I use:

```
et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0)) {
                //do dis
                return true;
                }
            else if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1)) {
                //do dat
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I press 0, do dis works. But when I press 1, do dat won't trigger. Why is that so? D: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfect. May be you can try putting Toast.makeText(...) to see where you are getting problem..

Comment: It is but when I press 1, 1 only is written on the edittext and nothing more. Don't know why :(